# Customize font-size depending on locale in Vue3/Laravel8?

Tags: html, css, laravel, vue.js, localization

I am working on a `Vue3/Laravel8` app, that has to support `english` and `arabic` languages. Problem is that there is a huge font-size difference between the `en` and `ar` locales:

[image: Sample to illustrate font size difference]

I've been looking for a while now for a way to change the `arabic font-size` but it doesn't seem simple.

First I tried finding a way in `vue-i18n` without success. It would be most convenient if that is possible.

Then I tried going the `CSS` route, using the `:lang(ar)` selector but it depends on `html` or in my case `laravel.blade` and controlling project language seems to be a hassle, creating middleware and controllers.

Is there a convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Vue 3.2 introduced some new features for single file components (SFC):
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#state-driven-dynamic-css

So in your case you could try something like this (untested):

```
<template>
    <div class="text">hello</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            lang: 'en',
        },
    },
    computed() {
        fontSize() {
            if (this.lang === 'ar') {
                return '1.5em';
            }
            return '1em';
        },
    },
}
</script>

<style>
.text {
    font-size: v-bind(fontSize);
}
</style>
```